# How design Employee table for many phone numbers?

Tags: database-design

Let's say you're designing an Employee table and have to accommodate different phone numbers..  Home, Work, and Cell for now but I suppose there could be others in the future.  Let's also say that the business cares to know what kind of cell phone each employee uses.  How would you design it?

Here's a denormalized way.  Simple, but then means adding a column for any new phone type:

**Employee**

- EmployeeId
- EmployeeLastName
- EmployeeFirstName
- EmployeeHomePhone
- EmployeeWorkPhone
- EmployeeCellPhone
- CellPhoneId

**CellPhone**

- CellPhoneId
- CellPhoneMake
- CellPhoneModel

Here's a more normalized/extensible way, but then there's figuring out where to put the CellPhone make/model info for phone numbers of type = cell (but not type = home or work):

**Employee**

- EmployeeId
- EmployeeLastName
- EmployeeFirstName

**EmployeePhone**

- EmployeePhoneId
- EmployeePhoneNumber
- PhoneTypeId

**PhoneType**

- PhoneTypeId
- PhoneTypeName
- CellPhoneTypeId <-- that's null for non-cell numbers? Seems like bad
  design.

My tendency is always to lean toward extensible (though more complex) that toward simple (but less extensible), but here I'm not sure.. especially when you consider that an employee will likely never have but 1 of each type of phone.  If you go extensible, future code can't then make that assumption and would always have to accommodate the possibility of multiple numbers of the same type (which isn't very realistic).

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596972/how-to-set-customer-table-with-multiple-phone-numbers-relational-database-des I'd personaly go for @mrjoltcola option 2)Extensibility

Answer (score 1):

*Employee*
   **EmployeeID** 
  EmployeeLastName, EmployeeFirstName

*Phone*
  **PhoneID** 
  PhoneTypeID, PhoneNumber

*Phonetype*
 
  **PhoneTypeID** 
  Phonemake, Phonemodel

*EmployeePhone*
**EmployeeID, Contact**
PhoneId, Notes

Where I'd recommend that `Phonetype` be dropped altogether. Realistically, it's not relevant - and it'll very soon become filled with stale garbage. I can't see that any high-power executive is going to feel the need to bother themselves with informing IT of the details of their latest toy. After all, IT should know automatically, shouldn't they?

I'd add a `Contact` field - look, I'm not that good on field names, OK? I mean a `reason for contact` which could be 'work' or 'home' or 'weekends' or 'Golf Club (Thursdays)' or whatever. `Notes` could be used for well - notes, like `Ask for Jacinta` if the `contact` is 'medical emergency' for instance.

As for having multiple phones - A doctor I know carries THREE cellphones - that's in addition to his office phone, practice phone, at least 2 office-in-hospital phones, public phone-at-home and privae phone-at-home (and multiple homes as well...) It's a wonder he can remember all of the numbers...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Phone
ID 
Name 
Number 
Type ENUM('Work', 'Home','Cell')

Employee
ID 
EmployeeLastName 
EmployeeFirstName 

EmployeePhone
ID
EmployeeID
PhoneID
```